# German expression for "learning by ear"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, expression

I saw this expression [*"learning from ear"*](https://www.dw.com/en/top-stories/learning-by-ear/s-11908) on DW, similar to the better know expression [*"playing by ear"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_by_ear). I want to know what the equivalent for this is in German.

Both expressions are also used in other languages, e.g. in Spanish: [*"aprendiendo de oído"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aprendiendo+de+o%C3%ADdo%22), French: [*""apprendre à l'oreille""*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apprendre+%C3%A0+l%27oreille%22), etc...

Answer (score 3):

The German term for *learning by ear* is *nach Gehör lernen*, which literally translates to "learning by listening", and is formed just as the spanish term *apprendiendo de oído* by using a nominalized form of the verb. However, while in the Spanish term the participle is used, German uses a different way of forming a noun in this particular case: *Gehör* is also "the ability to hear". The term is in the phrase *sich Gehör verschaffen* "to make oneself heard", literally "to gain hearing for oneself".

Similarly, *nach Gehör spielen* is the term for *playing by ear*.